# Removing specific elements from ArrayList by enum value

Tags: java

I have to remove elements from an ArrayList, but I could not make it work. I have to collect the oldest book name per each genre.

```
List<BookItem> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new BookItem("TitleName1", 1950, "NOVEL"));
list.add(new BookItem("TitleName2", 1970, "HORROR"));
list.add(new BookItem("TitleName3", 1954, "NOVEL"));
list.add(new BookItem("TitleName4", 1989, "HORROR"));
list.add(new BookItem("TitleName5", 1990, "HUMOR"));
list.add(new BookItem("TitleName6", 1995, "HUMOR"));
```

For example, in case above the desired result would be "TitleName1,TitleName2,TitleName5".

I tried the following code to achieve that, but I did not receive the desired result. BookGenre is of enum type.

```
public List<BookItem> getOldestBookPerGenre(List<BookItem> bookItems){
    List<BookItem> genreList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<BookItem> returnList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0; i < BookGenre.values().length; i++){
        for(BookItem item: bookItems) {
            if (item.getBookGenre().ordinal() == i) {
                genreList.add(item);
            }
        }
        if (genreList.size() > 0) {
            genreList.sort(compareByYear);
            returnList.add(genreList.get(0));
        }
        genreList.clear();
    }
    return returnList;
}
```

Comment: In the class BookItem, override equals and hashcode and also implement comparable and comparator for different types of sorting.

Comment: take a look on groupingBy of java streaming api

Comment: @B_Osipiuk I need to do it without java8 features

Comment: I don't think you need to override equals and hashCode for this, nor implement Comparable; the line `genreList.sort(compareByYear);` implies that compareByYear is a comparator, so show us the code for the comparator.

Comment: genreList.sort(new Comparator<BookItem>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(BookItem bookItem, BookItem t1) {
                        Integer year1 = bookItem.getReleaseDate();
                        Integer year2 = t1.getReleaseDate();
                        return year1.compareTo(year2);
                    }
                });

Comment: Judging from the constructor you use, the releaseDate is *not* of type integer, but of type String. This means the comparator you posted in the comments may be faulty, as Strings are compared differently than integers. Can you please specify, what your wrong result is?

Comment: @kopaka sorry, releaseDate is of type int. Its my misstake in this post

Comment: I have run your code, printed and my result is exactly as you wrote:


                List<BookItem> oldestBookPerGenre = getOldestBookPerGenre(list);
                oldestBookPerGenre.forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getTitle()));


TitleName1
TitleName2
TitleName5

Comment: so could you provide full code?
My bet is something is wrong either in your getter in BookItem or the way you check if you "receive the desired result".
The method itself looks good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy with java stream, but as you say you can't use Java8 here you have another solution:

```
public List<BookItem> getOldestBookPerGenre(List<BookItem> bookItems) {
    Map<String, BookItem> oldestBookByGenre = new HashMap<>();

    for (BookItem bookItem : bookItems) {
        oldestBookByGenre.putIfAbsent(bookItem.getGenre(), bookItem);
        if (Integer.parseInt(bookItem.getYear()) < Integer.parseInt(oldestBookByGenre.get(bookItem.getGenre()).getYear())) {
            oldestBookByGenre.put(bookItem.getGenre(), bookItem);
        }
    }

    return new ArrayList<>(oldestBookByGenre.values());
}
```

Output list, given the question input:

```
BookItem{title='TitleName2', year='1970', novel='HORROR'}
BookItem{title='TitleName1', year='1950', novel='NOVEL'}
BookItem{title='TitleName5', year='1990', novel='HUMOR'}
```

Comment: NullPointerException at this code if (Integer.parseInt(bookItem.getYear()) < Integer.parseInt(oldestBookByGenre.get(bookItem.getGenre()).getYear()))

Comment: I tryed the method I write and didn't see any NPE. You could only have any exceptions if you have null elements in the list or the year is not parsable to int. It is easy to check for that so it won't happen

Answer (score 0):

To get the oldest element from the `ArrayList` you can use Java [streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) (`stream()`, `filter(...)`, `min(...)`, etc).

It isn't exactly your script but you can easily see how the logic works and therefore adapt it with your code.

This example searchs for the oldest NOVEL book:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<BookItem> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new BookItem("TitleName1", 1950, "NOVEL"));
        list.add(new BookItem("TitleName2", 1970, "HORROR"));
        list.add(new BookItem("TitleName3", 1954, "NOVEL"));
        list.add(new BookItem("TitleName4", 1989, "HORROR"));
        list.add(new BookItem("TitleName5", 1990, "HUMOR"));
        list.add(new BookItem("TitleName6", 1995, "HUMOR"));

        BookItem oldestNovel = list.stream()
            .filter(element -> element.genre.equals("NOVEL"))
            .min((el1, el2) -> { if(el1.year == el2.year) return 0; return el1.year < el2.year ? -1 : 1; })
            .get();

        System.out.println(oldestNovel.title);
    }

    static class BookItem
    {
        String title = "";
        int year = 0;
        String genre = "";
        public BookItem(String title, int year, String genre)
        {
            this.title = title;
            this.year  = year;  
            this.genre = genre;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
TitleName1
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have to do it without Stream API

Comment: @user12337268 but you didn't notice it in your question... I spent 30 minutes to write and test this :(

Comment: I am really sorry for that :(

Comment: @user12337268 but why you don't want to use streams? Are so clear and useful

Comment: It'`s the condition of the task to solve this problem without java8